# Symfony 2 and Twig from MySql

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to create a basic CMS in Symfony2. Is it possible to "translate" twig code from mysql to controller somehow?

For example let say in mysql there is

```
{% include 'FOO::FOO.html.twig' %}
```

When I get it from orm how to make it load the template instead of just echo

{% include 'FOO::FOO.html.twig' %}

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the internal Lexer, parser and compiler of twig to get a php object representation of your templates:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/internals.html

Comment: Can you please give an example in action?